# QJsonArrays are not properly retrieved from QJsonObject

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt, qt5

In the project I'm currently working on there I use Qt's JSON functionality to store the state of a graph, where every component of the system recursively calls the `toJson`-functions of its members for serialization. This works fine, but I run into a weird issue when deserializing the JSON file.

As a test that illustrates the problem, I've created the following example code:

```
#include <QtCore/QJsonArray>
#include <QtCore/QJsonDocument>
#include <QtCore/QJsonObject>
#include <QtDebug>

int main() {
  auto document{QJsonDocument::fromJson("{\n"
                                        "  \"o1\" : {\n"
                                        "    \"i1\" : [\"l1\", \"l2\", \"l3\"],\n"
                                        "    \"i2\": 3.14\n"
                                        "  },\n"
                                        "  \"o2\" : {\n"
                                        "    \"i2\": 2.718,\n"
                                        "    \"i1\" : [\"l1\", \"l2\", \"l3\"]\n"
                                        "  }\n"
                                        "}")};
  qDebug() << "is the document an object:" << document.isObject();
  auto document_object{document.object()};

  auto object_1_value{document_object.value("o1")};
  qDebug() << "is o1 an object:" << object_1_value.isObject();
  auto object_1{object_1_value.toObject()};

  auto inner_1_value{object_1.value("i1")};
  qDebug() << "is i1 an array:" << inner_1_value.isArray();
  auto inner_1{inner_1_value.toArray()};
  qDebug() << "i1:" << inner_1;

  auto inner_1_inner_value{inner_1.at(0)};
  qDebug() << "is i1[0] an array:" << inner_1_inner_value.isArray();
  auto inner_1_inner{inner_1_inner_value.toArray()};
  qDebug() << "i1[0]:" << inner_1_inner;

  return 0;
}
```

Here, I am first querying `o1`, then try to get the array stored under `i1`.
However, I get the following output:

```
is the document an object: true
is o1 an object: true
is i1 an array: true
i1: QJsonArray([["l1","l2","l3"]])
is i1[0] an array: true
i1[0]: QJsonArray([["l1","l2","l3"]])
```

It seems like Qt stores the returned array into a useless one-element array; in my other code, `at(0)` solved the issue, but here even that does not work.

I would be very glad if someone could help me find a solution to reliably (and preferably hacklessly) read nested JSON arrays with Qt, as I truly do not understand the issue.
I am on Linux 5.6.11 with gcc 9.3.0 and Qt 5.14.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the brace initialization. When you do assignment-style initialization instead, it works.

```
// instead of
auto inner_1{inner_1_value.toArray()};
// use
auto inner_1 = inner_1_value.toArray();
// same for all other brace inits
```

What I think happens is the classic clash between brace initialization and list initialization via a `std::initializer_list` constructor, in this case this one:

```
QJsonArray::QJsonArray(std::initializer_list<QJsonValue> args);
```

You want to brace-init a `QJsonArray`, but `std::initializer_list` takes precedence and what you actually instantiate is a `QJsonArray` with one item which is again a `QJsonArray`.

Often you see this problem explained with `std::vector<int>` and the two clashing ctors:

```
vector(size_type count);
vector(std::initializer_list<int> init);
```

Comment: Oh, I hadn’t thought of that. Thanks a lot!